# How to find if an enum implementing an interface has overriden the methods?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I am trying to use Reflection to determine which types of my enumerator are valid for the data I need to send. The structure is below. I am taking the MyEnum type as input to my service which informs me what type of request I am dealing with and what I need to do in order to the process that data.

So I am checking that the value they give me does match MyEnum by:

```
return value != null ? MyEnum.valueOf(value.trim().toUppercase()) != null : false;
```

However, I am NOT validating if the MyEnum instance they requested has method1 and method2 implementations or if it will default to throw UnsupportedOperationException.  I tried reflection on the class to gather the Override annotations, but I don't know how to reflect on the methods declared inside the annoyomous enum classes like TYPE_A or TYPE_B. My reflection attempts keep scanning MyEnum.class and not the annoyomous classes I want to.

How can I check if the implementation exists without invoking the methods? Here is my code.

```
public interface MyEnumInterface {

    default MyRequest method1(MyRequest request){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The operation you are trying to do is not yet supported!");
    }
    default boolean method2(MyRequest request){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The operation you are trying to do is not yet supported!");
    }
}

public enum MyEnum implements MyEnumInterface  {

    TYPE_A {
        @Override
        public MyRequest method1(MyRequest request){
            // Logic
            request.setStatus("SAVING");
            return MyRequestService.persist(request);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean method2(MyRequest request){
            request.setStatus("PROCESSING");
            // Logic...
            return true;
        }
    },
    TYPE_B {
        @Override
        public MyRequest method1(MyRequest request){
            // Different Logic...
            return request;
        }
    },
    TYPE_C {
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve with this? I feel a design smell here.

Comment: Our application accepts different file types and processes requests differently depending on the type of file given. Such as: CSV, KML, TXT, PDF, ZIP, etc. The first interface method defines how to validate that File Type as input. The second interface method defines how to create the requested file type. Such as input as CSV and output file as CSV or input as TXT and output file as PDF, etc.. I tried to simply the question here without my real code because I have a lot of specific code that is not related to my question.

Comment: Hmm, I'd probably not define the code directly in the enum but use it as a token to get the correct handler (which would then be different classes). But besides that couldn't you just implement "identity" default methods, i.e. methods that do nothing (depends on the definition of "nothing" for the method, e.g. validation could just return true) and call them anyways?

Comment: I originally had them as separate classes, but I am configuring the code so that eventually all the types will be compatible with themselves and I don't want a bunch of classes like CSV2CSV and CSV2KML and CSV2TXT, etc. -- Then if I make the default to do nothing and invoke the method and it is implemented I don't want that process to run yet. I would only be fine invoking the method if I can ensure that the overridden implementation will not be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Method.getDeclaringClass`.

For Example:

```
interface Inter {
  default void foo() {
    System.out.println("Q48564340.Inter.foo()");
  }

  default void bar() {
    System.out.println("Q48564340.Inter.bar()");
  }
}

enum Enum implements Inter {
  A {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
      System.out.println("Q48564340.Enum.A.{...}.foo()");
    }
  }
}

Method fooA = Enum.A.getClass().getMethod("foo");
Method barA = Enum.A.getClass().getMethod("bar");
System.out.println(fooA.getDeclaringClass() == Inter.class);// false
System.out.println(barA.getDeclaringClass() == Inter.class);// true
```

So you can know the method `bar` has been overrrided.